# Prove function f is surjective.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

f: $\mathbb{R}$ $\to$ $\mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function and $\overline{f(\mathbb{N})} = \mathbb{R}$. Prove that f is surjective.
I've thought alot about this but i still haven't find a clue. I would really appreciate any help or a hint.

Comment: Hint:  use the condition to deduce that $f$ must take arbitrarily large positive and negative values.  Use continuity to finish.

Comment: The same question was asked here not long ago.

Comment: Does there exist such function???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equation $\overline{f(\mathbb{N})} = \mathbb{R}$ means every real number is the limit of a sequence of points in $f(\mathbb N)$. Since $f$ is continuous, you can apply the intermediate value theorem on every closed interval. Can you complete the proof?

Comment: From the duplicate: "Take $b \in \mathbb R$. By hypothesis, it exists $a_1,a_2 \in \mathbb N$ such that 
$f(a_1) \in (b-3/2, b-1/2)$ and $f(a_2) \in (b+1/2, b+3/2)$.

Then by the intermediate value theorem, it exists $a \in (a_1, a_2)$ such that $f(a)=b$."